# Do we really grep c++ style casts?

Tags: c++, casting

When I read about C++ casts in books there is always a point that it's useful because you can easy grep your sources for `.*_cast<` to find out usages.

But does anyone really use this? I can't really remember for all my career that I would need such feature. For user types it's more practical to grep by type name even if you haven't IDE support. Moreover, as you can still use old C-style casting if you will search for C++-casts you will have a chance miss all type conversions.

Do I miss something or advice "use C++ casts because it's easy to grep" isn't really usable in practice?

Comment: There are basically only 4 types so therefore it should be quite simple to grep for those 4 variations. It's certainly easier than grepping for c style casts. But I see what you mean about does anyone ever do it. I personally never have.

Comment: Yes, but you can't protect that another developer in your team will use old C-style casting. So your grep always has chances for fail.

Comment: @VadimKey Other developers is why you have coding standards and code reviews.

Answer (score 7):

Burn those books. Use a C++ style cast simply because they are *better*:

A `static_cast` makes a *compile-time* check.

A `dynamic_cast` will return `nullptr` if a run-time cast is invalid, or throw an exception (depending on what you're casting).

A `reinterpret_cast` is an expressive way of asserting to the compiler (and reader of your code) that you know what you're doing.

A `const_cast` can be used to explicitly remove or introduce `const`-ness. Since casting away `const`-ness can introduce *undefined behaviour* into your program, it's nice to make it explicit.

A C-style cast offers none of these features.

Comment: These are Stroustrup and Alexandrescu books, so I would like to avoid :)

That's obvious that C++ casts are better, my question do you grep for c++ casts ever?

Comment: Yeah you should keep Stroustrup, but I still think *searchability* is a pithy reason. In the last 20 years I've never had the need to search for my casts.

Comment: Searching for `dynamic_cast` is useful if you want to avoid the runtime check.

Comment: I also never grepped them. But what i noticed is c-style casts can "accidently" cast constness away + do what a reinterpret cast can do. So you also have some side effects maybe if you don't use the c++ style cast.

Comment: @Hayt: Yes, they would do. I've added `const_cast` to my answer.